# How to make the web page fit into UIWebView for testing using Selenium iPhone driver

Tags: iphone, selenium, uiwebview, mobile-safari, driver

I am testing a web app by running selenium test scripts on an iPad simulator using Selenium iPhone driver. The app opens in UIWebView inside the simulator. However the top part of the app (title , toolbar etc.) gets hidden from view. I am able to see the top part when I drag down and hold the bottom part of the app.

1) How can I make UIWebView make the app visible fully? I guess it is because of the difference in iPad simulator version used in the iPhone driver source code and one that I am using to launch the app(iOS 6.0). However I have no idea how to proceed with this as but I'm not familiar enough with iOS development.

2) Is testing in UIWebview same as testing the app in mobile Safari? Is there any way I can test the app in mobile Safari in an iPad using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you want to test the website, not the iphone app.

Then you could just as easily open it in mobile safari and use bookmark to view full screen (if you wanted the app to go fullscreen, you would need to do it programmatically)

Comment: I want to perform automation testing of the website using Selenium; so need to start the safari in iPad through Selenium scripts to execute every new test case. To the best of my knowledge, [ selenium iphone driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver) opens the app only in UIWebView. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Ipad storyboard file located at src\resource. The webView setting Y coordinate  was set to -84 and I changed it to 0. This might help

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to find the Y coord settings in src/ resource. Can you provide a screenshot or describe more please.